# Meant vs would mean

Tags: tenses

I am writing a story, but I got stuck on this sentence:
No one dared to volunteer, as that meant risking one's life.

Does this sound correct/natural?
Or should I change this sentence to:
No one dared to volunteer, as that would mean risking one's life.

Which seems better and more correctly stated?
Thank you.

Comment: EL&U is not a writers' workshop; your question cannot be answered definitively as currently phrased. I would review the [help] and see if you can rework it into something suitable to our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are correct.  The choice is yours:

- If you want to convey that *risking one's life* is certain if one volunteered, then "No one dared to volunteer, as that meant risking one's life." is **better**.
- If you want to express *risking one's life* as a hypothetical situation or something that might happen if one volunteered, then "No one dared to volunteer, as that would mean risking one's life." is **better**.